# How should I deallocate pointers allocated using new stored on std::stack

Tags: c++

I have a program that allocates pointers on a stack.

```
#include <stack>

class A{};

int main()
{
    std::stack<A*> pAs;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        A* pA = new A{};
        pAs.push(pA);
    }   
}
```

The following is what I was doing.

```
    while (!pAs.empty())
    {
        delete pAs.top();
        pAs.pop(); 
    }
```

My logic in doing this is that `delete pAs.top()` deletes the pointer and I have to remove the remaining pointer that points to an "invalid memory location" using `pAs.pop()` myself. I tried to test if the size decreases with every deletion

```
        while (!pAs.empty())
        {
            delete pAs.top();
            std::cout << pAs.size() << '\n' 
        }
```

but I got some error saying some file not loaded.

Or maybe this?

```
        while (!pAs.empty())
        {
            pAs.pop(); //Does .pop() automatically deallocate memory?
        }
```

What should I do?

Comment: "I got some error saying some file not loaded."  The exact error message, please?

Comment: @NateEldredge It didn't actually give the error message. Visual studio opens a new window and says "wntdll.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module ntdll.dll"

Comment: Your first code is correct, stick with that or even better use smart pointers and avoid `new` and `delete` completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I deallocate pointers allocated using new

By storing them in a smart pointer upon creation, and destroying that smart pointer when you desire to deallocate.

> stored on std::stack

Example:

```
{
    std::stack<std::unique_ptr<A>> pAs;
    pAs.push(std::make_unique<A>());
}  // the dynamic object is correctly deallocated here
```

---

> ```
> //Does .pop() automatically deallocate memory?
> ```

`std::stack::pop` only erases the element from the stack. It doesn't do anything else, for example, it won't call `delete` on the element. If the element is a bare pointer with sole ownership of dynamic memory, then that memory will leak.

---

P.S. Avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation. Consider whether `std::stack<A>` would be a more efficient choice.